How to set popup placement target on bottom using MAUI XAML C# .Net 8.0
How to set popup placement target on bottom? Please see this screenshot.
I want to place the popup on bottom. I have click on three dots on grid  header control, but I can not set popup position exact on three dots button.
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         x:Class="PopupPosition.PopupView"
         HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End">
</toolkit:Popup>

private void btnShow_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var popupview = new PopupView();
    popupview.Anchor = btnShow;
    popupview.Anchor.TranslateTo(0, 0);

    this.ShowPopup(popupview);
}

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.70" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.70" />
    </ItemGroup>



I want to place the popup on bottom. I have click on three dots on grid header control, but I can not set popup position exact on three dots button.

Like Liqun said: You can wrap the layout with a Border and set the BackgroundColor of Border to transparent and set the margin for the layout in the Border. But to be honest, it's not elegant enough. You can ask a feature request on GitHub, let our developers know and deal with it.
